# Issue with simplecursor adapter in android

Tags: android, android-spinner, simplecursoradapter

I am populating a spinner with cursor adapter but my problem here is I am unable to understand how to give "from" and "to" of "SimpleCusorAdapter".

From examples available I could understand that FROM is the column name and To is the column ID, My table code goes as below where I am dynamically creating columns so in this case how can I use column name and column ID. Below is the code.

```
String Tablename = "table 1";
    String Column1 = "RegionID";
    String Column2 = "RegionName";
    String Column3 = "Currency";

    // Table Create starts here
    public final String r_Table = "CREATE TABLE " + Tablename + " (" + Column1+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , " + Column2 + " TEXT, " + Column3 + " Text) ";
```

I managed to give the cursor adapter but it is giving me the error "**The Simple Cursor adapter is undefined**". Below is the cursor code.

```
SimpleCursorAdapter A=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, r.retrivedata(),r.Column2.toString(),r.c.getColumnIndex(r.Column2.toString()));
```

Above retrive data retrives cursor from another class.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance
Siva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From examples available I could understand that FROM is the column
>   name and To is the column ID,

The `from` array represents the names of the columns that the adapter will use to extract the data from the `Cursor`. The `to` array represents the array with the ids of the views from the row layout file on which the adapter will bind the data.

> My table code goes as below where I am dynamically creating columns so
>   in this case how can I use column name and column ID.

You aren't using dynamic tables as you probably just declare those names once in your app at start and never change. To create the `SimpleCursorAdapter` you'll use:

```
String[] from = {Column1, Column2}; // assuming that in the cursor you'll have this two columns
int[] to = {R.id.firstViewOnWhichToBindDataOfColumn1, R.id.secondViewOnWhichToBindDataFromColumn2}
SimpleCursorAdapter A=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, null, from, to);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Luksprog... It was very explanatory. But I have one query here "**R.id.firstViewOnWhichToBindDataOfColumn1**" I am using the data into a spinner, so here can I give the ID of the spinner.

Comment: @siva That id must come from the row layout and is not the id of the `Spinner`. In your case if you use `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` the id should be `android.R.id.text1`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my confusing, this will solve my problem but for learning purpose can you help me how to determine which layout need to be used for different purpose. If possible can you provide me with some link.